# Problem with apt public keys in docker image building

Tags: debian, apt, gpg

I have problem after upgrading PHP image from 8.0 to PHP image 8.1 and on stackoverflow they sent me there

this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM php:8.1-apache AS apache
RUN a2enmod rewrite

WORKDIR /bin
WORKDIR ../

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0E98404D386FA1D9 6ED0E7B82643E131 F8D2585B8783D481 BDE6D2B9216EC7A8

RUN apt update \
    && apt install \
    curl \
    git \
    unzip \
    cron \
    libzip-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    pkg-config \
    libssl-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    wget \
    libcap2-bin \
    procps \
    -y \
    && setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /usr/sbin/apache2 \
    && chown www-data:www-data /var/log/apache2 \
    && wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/releases/download/0.12.6.1-3/wkhtmltox_0.12.6.1-3.bookworm_amd64.deb \
    && apt install -y ./wkhtmltox_0.12.6.1-3.bookworm_amd64.deb \
    && rm wkhtmltox_0.12.6.1-3.bookworm_amd64.deb \
    && apt-get clean autoclean \
    && apt-get autoremove --yes
    etc...
```

During image building I have error;

```
[0mGet:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease [151 kB]
Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease [52.1 kB]
Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease [48.0 kB]
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131 NO_PUBKEY F8D2585B8783D481
Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm-updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0E98404D386FA1D9 NO_PUBKEY 6ED0E7B82643E131
Err:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 54404762BBB6E853 NO_PUBKEY BDE6D2B9216EC7A8
```

If I am adding line:

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 0E98404D386FA1D9 6ED0E7B82643E131 F8D2585B8783D481 BDE6D2B9216EC7A8
```

There is error:

```
[91mE: gnupg, gnupg2 and gnupg1 do not seem to be installed, but one of them is required for this operation
```

If I am adding apt installer of gnupg in dockerfile... there is the same error with public keys so I cannot install it

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting the missing key errors when I try your Dockerfile. I removed the `RUN apt-key ...` line and the rest just works. Maybe the `php:8.1-apache` was buggy at the time you wrote this question.

Since it is difficult to test a solution to a problem that can't be replicated, I only have a suggestion: You could take the key files from a working system and just copy them into the image (they should be in `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`). That should return apt to a working state.

Other options that should work:

1. If you already have a valid local cache of the available packages you could just (re-)install the `debian-archive-keyring` package, which contains the files. But on a fresh Docker image this is not likely.
2. You can just download the [`debian-archive-keyring` .deb](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/debian-archive-keyring) file from a mirror and install it manually.